# Query an XDocument Query doesn't work when element/root has Namespace as atribute

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

The problem is that I can not get any results if the node contains namespace/attribute. This is the code:

```
Dim xmlFromDisk = XDocument.Load("customers.xml")
Dim ukCustomers = <ukCustomers>
                    <%= From cust In xmlFromDisk...<Customer> _
                    Where cust.<Country>.Value = "UK" _
                    Select cust %>
                  </ukCustomers>
```

When I have the following customers.xml the query works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
    <Country>UK</Country>
  </Customer>
  </Customers>
```

When I have the following customers.xml the query DOES NOT work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Customer>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
    <Country>UK</Country>
  </Customer>
  </Customers>
```

The only difference is the namespace  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" in the Customers element.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, so you need to specify the namespace as well. `xmlns="..."` indicates the default namespace for any unqualified descendant elements.

I don't know how you'd do it in an XML literal in VB, but in C# you'd just write:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
var ukCustomers = doc.Root
                     .Elements(ns + "Customer")
                     .Where(x => (string) x.Element(ns + "Country") == "UK");
```

EDIT: This is the equivalent VB code as shown by Reflector and hacked around a bit by me:

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/"
Dim ukCustomers =
   (From x In doc.Root.Elements(DirectCast((ns + "Customer"), XName))
    Where (CStr(x.Element(ns + "Country")) = "UK")
    Select x)
```

Comment: Can you please send me the vb.net version. I don't know why but I can not convert it. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul: Not right now, I'm afraid. Can you just compile it as C#, then run Reflector on it?

Comment: My project is in VB.NET and I have never used Reflector. When you have time just post only the LINQ Query for VB.NET. Thank you again.

Comment: @Paul: Okay, I'll see when I can find the time - but it's not likely to be for another 3 hours. I suggest you try to find some VB LINQ to XML tutorials which show the use of namespaces.

Comment: @Paul: I've updated it with what I *hope* is the right code - try it, then make sure you really understand it so you can write similar code yourself.