# Get all XML fields of certain tag

Tags: xml, vb.net

How would I get all the  fields in a list from this XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc_type_name SYSTEM  "R:\ftproot\graphics\ONIX_BookProduct_3.0_reference.dtd">
<ONIXMessage xmlns="http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/ONIX_BookProduct_Release2.1_reference.xsd">
    <Header>
        <FromCompany>A company</FromCompany>
        <FromEmail>support@acompany.com</FromEmail>
        <SentDate>201408101343</SentDate>
        <MessageNote>Generated by a company</MessageNote>
        <DefaultLanguageOfText>eng</DefaultLanguageOfText>
    </Header>
    <Product>
        <WorkIdentifier>
            <WorkIDType>15</WorkIDType>
            <IDValue>9781861511126</IDValue>
        </WorkIdentifier>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <RecordReference>9781861511690</RecordReference>
        <NotificationType>02</NotificationType>
        <RecordSourceType>01</RecordSourceType>
        <RecordSourceName>A company</RecordSourceName>
    </Product>
</ONIXMessage>
```

First I've done this:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = New XDocument
    Dim products As List(Of XElement)
```

Then tried each of the following to no avail, always comes back as an empty list:

```
products = xmlDoc.Element("ONIXMessage").Descendants("Product").ToList()
products = xmlDoc.Descendents("ONIXMessage").Descendants("Product").ToList()
products = xmlDoc.Descendants("Product").ToList()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing the fact that your XML uses a namespace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859789/query-an-xdocument-query-doesnt-work-when-element-root-has-namespace-as-atribut.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know what the namespace is! Is there any other way around this? Is there a way to temporarily delete the ONIXMessage tag and then read it? For instance.